# Regular expression in javascript to check date is embded with text

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I need to check whether the text contains a date part with it.

for ex:
`mytext_12/26/2011_11:51_AM or someText_12/26/2011_13:51_PM` have a date part it returns true.

I am not too good with expressions so looking for one. the format of the date part is fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To merely test for the presence of a date in a string...

```
var containsDate = ~str.search(/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}/);
```

If you wanted to check the time at the end too, add `_\d{1,2}:\d{2}_(?:AM|PM)`.

Comment: thank for the post but i think it is not helping me out i will let you know how  function checkDate() {
                var textValue = $("#txtName").val();
                var isThere = textValue.search(/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}/) ? true: false;
                alert(isThere);
            } so i have entered the value as abc in the textbox txtname it is returning me true always whether it has date part or not

Comment: @ankur - note the `~` in front `str.search(...)` in alex's answer - this allows for the fact that `.search()` returns -1 if the pattern doesn't match and -1 is truthy. You can simplify this by using `.test()` instead; it returns a boolean: `var isThere = /\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}/.test(textValue);`

Comment: @Alex can you paste the complete string with time part appended with this _\d{1,2}:\d{2}_(?:AM|PM).

Comment: @ankur I don't quite understand what you mean.

Comment: @Alex iwant to check whether it contains am or pm also "Annual_12/7/2011_234234" this string is invalid but it returns true value so how to ensure that it is a proper string with proper time format . for checking this is a proper string "Annual_12/7/2011_3:56_PM" i hope you got my point.

Comment: @ankur Use `~str.search(/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}_\d{1,2}:\d{2}_(AM|PM)/)`. The `am` or `pm` will appear in the first capturing group (`1`).